# Radar Chart from Pandas Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table, radar-chart

I'm looking for a way to generate a radar chart from a pandas pivot table that looks like this. I have seen the code from http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/radar_chart.html, but they seem to be using a totally different format for the data. Is there any direct way this can be done with the data as I have it?

```
FinalOutcome            Lost   Won   All
decision     gameStage                  
Bet          Flop        NaN  0.08  0.08
             Turn      -0.32  0.08 -0.02
Bet half pot River     -0.32  0.12  0.01
             Turn      -0.01  0.14  0.06
Call         Flop      -0.16  0.01 -0.12
             PreFlop   -0.06  0.09 -0.03
Check        Flop      -0.04  0.09 -0.01
             River     -0.02  0.04  0.00
             Turn      -0.03  0.06 -0.02
Fold         Flop      -0.06   NaN -0.06
             PreFlop   -0.02   NaN -0.02
             River     -0.03   NaN -0.03
             Turn      -0.06   NaN -0.06
```